# How to make pipe-delimited list in solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm working on legacy application that refreshes index on solr. I have following code:

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
...
LinkedList<String> addressesDelimitered = new LinkedList<>();
for(String a : student.addresses)
{
    addressesDelimitered.add(a);
}
doc.addField("AddressesDelimitered", addressesDelimitered);
...
documents.add(doc);
...
solr.add(documents);
solr.commit();
```

There is known problem with this field that it does not have all delimitered fields displayed in query results, for example string in this format:

```
Street|000|||City|00-000|Province|Country
```

is returned as:

```
Street||||City|
```

I have tried to use ClientUtils.escapeQueryChar, but I got similar result.

What is wrong with this string that it have removed parts? It looks like problem with special characters

**Edit:** I couldn't find settings.xml (there are only 4 files with that name in examples directory, none of them contains definition of AddressesDelimitered), but I can see in web browser that type of field is string ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWWFc.png))

Comment: Can you share how do you `schema.xml` file looks for the `AddressesDelimitered` field and the corresponding `fieldType`?

Comment: @JorgeLuis I found `schema.xml` on web administration page. Here is configuration of field: `<field name="AddressesDelimitered" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>`

Comment: Can you share the `fieldType` definition for the `string`? Normally the `string` type (`solr.StrField`) stores the entire string as a single token, if you're doing partial matching on that field, you must be applying some tokenizer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/whM1A.png)